# in Shiny, how to connect landing pages?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating Shiny app with multiple landing pages some of them need to be connected. 
The sample here shows that in the home page, the select input "home" is selected and in the dashboard body two widgets the 1st one is "clients" with action button "click here". I need this button to lead to the same landing page if i selected "Clients" from the SelectInput 
Or should I create a link to facilitate jumping to any page
Here is a GIF showing what I'm looking for [image: GIF]

```
UI
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(markdown)


title <- tags$a(href= NULL, tags$img(src ="BM_fl.png", onclick =     "selectInput('Home')", height = '55',  style = "padding-bottom:10px;"))
ui = fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("superhero"),
           dashboardPage(
             dashboardHeader(title = title, titleWidth = 230), 
             dashboardSidebar(selectInput("listofitems","Items     List",c("Home","Group","Clients"), selected = "Home")),
             dashboardBody(uiOutput("ui_myHome"),
                           uiOutput("ui_myclients")))) 


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$ui_myHome<-renderUI({if (input$listofitems == 'Home'){(
  fluidPage(
    widgetUserBox(
      title = "Clients",
      shiny::actionButton(inputId='clientsmainbutton', label="Click here"),
      type = 2, src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", color = "yellow"),
    widgetUserBox(
      title = "Facts",
      shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab1', label="Click here"),
      type = 2, src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", color = "yellow")))}

else if (input$listofitems == 'Clients'){(Clientsbutton<- fluidPage(
                                              widgetUserBox(title = "Global",shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab1', label="Click here"),
                                                type = 2, src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", 
                                                color = "red")))}})})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this and it works

```
Groupbutton<- fluidPage(widgetUserBox(title = "Group",shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab1', label="Click here"),type = 2, 
            src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg",color = "blue"))
Clientsbutton<-fluidPage(widgetUserBox(title = "Global",shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab1', label="Click here"),type = 2, 
            src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", color = "red"))
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){output$ui_myHome<-renderUI({
if (input$listofitems == 'Home'){(fluidPage(
    widgetUserBox(title = "Clients",
      shiny::actionButton(inputId='clientsmainbuttonId', label="Click here"),
      type = 2, src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", color = "yellow"),
    widgetUserBox(title = "Group",
      shiny::actionButton(inputId='GroupbuttonId', label="Click here"),
      type = 2, src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", color = "green")))}

else if (input$listofitems == 'Clients'){(Clientsbutton)}
else if (input$listofitems == 'Group'){(Groupbutton)} })  observeEvent(input$GroupbuttonId,{updateSelectInput(session,"listofitems","Items List", choices =c("Home","Group","Clients"), selected ="Group")},ignoreInit = TRUE)
observeEvent(input$clientsmainbuttonId,{updateSelectInput(session,"listofitems","Items List", choices =c("Home","Group","Clients"), selected = "Clients")},ignoreInit = TRUE)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try observeevent or conditional panel, honestly,I don't know how but I guess it will work

Comment: I will try both